# how to rename foreign key while creating tables

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

i have two models for `user` and `account`. It is a one to one relationship so i have `belongs_to :user` in account model.

I have migration script for `account` table i have `t.belongs_to :user, index: true`

When i run `rake db:migrate` it creates column user_id. I want the name as `user_account_id`.

I tried creating another migration script to change foreign key name from `user_id` to `user_account_id` and it works but how can change foreign key name while creating tables so i dont have to add another migration script?

Thanks

Comment: i dont think so. in that link the answer says creating new migration script to link two tables. what i am asking is, can i rename foreign key while creating table

Comment: Does `t.belongs_to :user_account` work? I know it feels wrong, but I'm looking at the rails source code and it seems to be the only workaround?.... (I'll add this as an answer if my hunch is correct)

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f648d7d39cffdcb973df661ccf35a89c805c3e04/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb#L185-L187

Comment: Also, why is this tagged as rails 3 **and** rails 4? Which version are you using? (Possibly even rails 5?!)

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_reference) `belongs_to` (`reference`) generates a name automatically and it is impossible to customize field name.
So for your case, you should generate it manually. 
Instead of:

```
t.belongs_to :user, index: true
```

Please try this:

```
  t.integer :user_account_id, null: false
...
add_foreign_key table_name, :users, column: :user_account_id, primary_key: :id
```

In the same migration.